# How can I create a custom html tag in the CKeditor wysiwyg editor?

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I've created a custom HTML tag that pulls information from my database and displays it. Basically it uses `preg_match_all` to parse the body of articles for `<profiletag>Person Name</profiletag>` and replaces this tag with html of the person's profile.

Now what I want is to allow my writers to insert this HTML (`<profiletag>Person Name</profiletag>`) from the WYSIWYG editor rather than having to go into the source and insert a tag into the html. When they write `<profiletag>` etc. in the WYSIWYG editor obviously it gets all messed up. I'm looking for something like [profile]Person Name[/profile] markup for them to include these tags in the WYSIWYG side.

Is this possible, and if so how can I implement this functionality?

Comment: I think you will need to create a custom plugin http://ckeditor.com/forums/Plugins/Customtag-plugin

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a custom filter. Filters are the check boxes you can set on input formats like 'Filtered HTML' and 'Full HTML'.

There is an example available in the examples module: https://www.drupal.org/project/examples

Basically, you need this:

1) You need to implement [hook_filter_info()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21filter%21filter.api.php/function/hook_filter_info/7) to let Drupal know there is a new filter
2) You need to a function to process the input. This is where you can use your regex.

I highly suggest looking at the examples module or any other modules that use filters.